# Existence of at least one compact orbit on the sphere

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Good morning,

I've came across this question during my researches. It seems apparently very simple, however I Googled a bit and I couldn't find the answer I was looking for.

The question is as follows: Is it true that **any** connected subgroup of $GL(d,\mathbb{R})$ admits at least one compact orbit on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ (or, if you prefer, on the projective space $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{R}^d))$?

Well, of course this is true if the subgroup is of the form $e^{tA},t\in\mathbb{R}$, but for more complicated subgroups I don't know. I guess that the main point that prevents the use of standard methods is that the subgroup is not, in general, (Zariski) closed. Thus many powerful results are not available. Nonetheless, I'm still guessing that the answer should be yes, but I cannot prove it.

If you can provide me with references, or showing me counter-examples, that would be great!

Thanks in advance for your kindness.

Regards

**EDIT**: in response to the comments below, I would like to narrow a bit the question.

In fact, what I am really interested in is the following setting: take any Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{a}$ of $\mathfrak{gl}(d,\mathbb{R})$, and consider the subgroup $G$ of $GL(d,\mathbb{R})$ generated by $\mathfrak{a}$, so to avoid nasty possibilities. Nonetheless, $G$ need not be algebraic.

Also, for any $g\in G$, the action on the sphere is intended to be $x\mapsto \frac{gx}{\|gx\|}$, for any $x\in\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - how is an arbitrary subgroup of $GL(d,\mathbb{R})$ supposed to act on the unit sphere?

Comment: I guess you could first retract to $SO(n)$ (by connectedness), but then the question would really only be about subgroups of $SO(n)$.

Comment: I guess, for $A\in GL(d,\mathbb{R})$ we consider the action $x\mapsto Ax/\|Ax\|$ on the unit sphere.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, indeed this is what I meant, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: The parenthesis around Zariski clearly indicate you do not assume algebraic, But do you assume the subgroup to be closed (a Lie subgroup ?) or path-connected ?. Apparently, there are nasty examples  otherwise ( https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1256063578 )

Comment: @user120527: I've added some more clarifications in my post. Thank for the reference anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true that for every continuous real linear finite dimensional representation of a connected Lie group there exists a closed orbit for the associated projective representation.

To see this it is enough to assume the group is solvable (as every connected Lie group has a cocompact solvable subgroup) and the representation is irreducible and faithful. It follows that the unipotent radical of the Zariski closure is trivial, thus our group is diagonalizable and the representation is either 1 or 2-dimensional. The 1-dim case is trivial and in the 2-dim case we get that the action on the projective line is transitive.

---

Here are some more details.

Let $A$ be the connected, simply connected Lie group associated with the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{a}$. The inclusion map $\mathfrak{a}\to \mathfrak{gl}_d(\mathbb{R})$ gives rise to a continuous homomorphism $A\to \text{GL}_d(\mathbb{R})$. The connected group alluded to in the (edited) question is the image of $A$ under this continuous homomorphism.
Thus we need to show that for every linear representation of a connected Lie group, the associated projective action has a closed orbit.

It is enough to show that a cocompact subgroup of $A$ has a closed orbit, as a cocompact subgroup (the stabilizer of a point in this orbit) of a cocompact subgroup is cocompact. Now, use the fact that every connected Lie group has a cocompact solvable subgroup. This is a standard fact (by factoring the solvable radical it is enough to observe this fact for adjoint semi-simple Lie groups, which are in fact real algebraic groups, then it is reduced to Borel's fixed point theorem, which is nothing but the "Zariski closed version of this question" which you seem to be aware of). We thus need to prove the claim: for every linear representation of a connected solvable group, the associated projective action has a closed orbit.
Obviously, it is enough to assume the representation is irreducible.

We thus need to prove the claim: for every continuous irreducible finite dimensional real linear representation of a connected solvable group $A$, the associated projective action has a closed orbit. 
Irreducible representations of solvable groups are either one or two dimensional. This follows for example from Lie-Kolchin (for an invariant line $\mathbb{C}\cdot v$ in the complexification, take the space generated by $v+\bar{v}$ and $v-\bar{v}$). In the 1-dim case the corresponding projective space is a singleton, and there is nothing to prove. in the 2-dim case the projective space is a topologically a circle. We are done by noting that the action of a connected group on a circle is either transitive or have a fixed point. Indeed, its orbits are homogeneous connected subsets, thus points or open intervals, and in the latter case any end point of the interval will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've awarded the bounty to your answer already, but I would like to take some time before accepting it, because I would like to check myself your explanation. This will take me some time, since I'm not an expert. If you feel like adding some more details, please go ahead, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you again! -Guido-

Comment: @guido, With pleasure. My answer was indeed brief, as  I am currently traveling and do not have much time, but I will provide more details when I am back. It will help me if you could let me know the less clear parts on your side.

Comment: From what I understand, the cocompact solvable subgroup should be the solvable radical, am I right? Then I have some difficulties concerning the statement: the unipotent radical of the Zariski closure should be trivial (here is my inexpertise, unfortunately). The rest is somewhat clear, since we are complexifying, the representation is either 1 or 2 dimensional (linked to the fact that the eigenvalues are complex or real, and the Lie Kolchin theorem), and then one studies the orbits (I believe we identify the projective line with the circle). This is what I understand, sorry for the mess.

Comment: @guido, I added details. Please let me know if anything remains unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation clarifies exactly all the points where I was a bit confused. I've got a last (small question). The fact that all these representation are 1 or 2 dimensional does not imply anything on the dimension of the compact orbits. Am I right? I mean, we can have, in general compact orbits of any dimension (I am thinking of irreducible groups where it seems strange to have circles). BTW, I am really grateful for your explanation. Again thank you very much!

Comment: The 1-2 dimensiinality is an artifact of the reduction steps in the proof. (varying the acting group) you can have compact orbits of unbounded dimension, as the example of the standard rep of SL_n shows.

Comment: I cannot express enough my gratitude. It was a pleasure to have this discussion with you! My bests -Guido-

Comment: Dear professor Bader, sorry to bother you again, but I realized that there is still a small point in the proof which puzzles me. Namely, I've understood that we can reduce everything to the case of real algebraic linear groups. Nonetheless to apply correctly the Borel Fixed point theorem we need to complexify to work on an algebraically closed field. The cocompact solvable connected subgroup that we find is thus a complex subgroup. But we would like to have it real. Is it automatic the passage to a real subgroup having all the required properties, or am I missing something? Bests, -Guido-

Comment: Are you concerned with the proof of the fact that every connected group has a cocompact solvable subgroup, or with the stuff comes after that?

Comment: My main issue is the connectedness of the cocompact solvable subgroup that we find. The theorem I found is the following (on the complex field): let H be a closed subgroup of G: then G/H cocompact iff H contains a maximal solvable connected subgroup (Borel-Tits IHS, prop 9.3). The equivalence follows using the fixed point theorem. I understand well that we find what we are looking for on C. How can we guarantee the existence of such a real group?

Comment: I know that any lie Group contains a cocompact subgroup, but in general we cannot guarantee that it is connected, so this is where I am a bit confused. In the other hand, at the beginning of your last paragraph, it seems implicitly stated that with the previous arguments we should find a cocompact solvable connected real group. Am I wrong? -Guido-

Comment: The last part using Lie Kolchin is clear. Many thanks in advance -Guido-

Comment: OK, I understand that what you miss is the fact that every semisimple Lie group has a solvable cocompact subgroup. A quick way to see that is by taking  the minimal parabolic subgroup in it, which is cocompact, and to note that the minimal parabolic itself has a normal cocompact solvale subgroup. These two facts should appear in any good book regarding semisimple Lie groups.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! From what I understand one considers the Iwasawa decomposition $G=KAN$ of a semisimple group $G$, therefore if we take $M$ the centralizer of $A$ in $K$, then $MAN$ is a minimal parabolic subgroup of $G$. The factor $AN$ now is cocompact solvable and connected, as desired. Am I right? -Guido-